# не получается использовать java mail в android

Tags: java, android, email

Добрый день.

Код:

```
Session session = null;
ProgressDialog pdialog = null;
Context context = null;
EditText reciep, sub, msg;
String rec, subject, textMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    context = this;

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    reciep = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_to);
    sub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_sub);
    msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_text);

    login.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    rec = reciep.getText().toString();
    subject = sub.getText().toString();
    textMessage = msg.getText().toString();

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("testfrom354@gmail.com", "p1234p1234");
        }
    });

    pdialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Sending Mail...", true);

    RetreiveFeedTask task = new RetreiveFeedTask();
    task.execute();
}

class RetreiveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try{
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("testfrom354@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(rec));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(textMessage, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
            Transport.send(message);
        } catch(MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdialog.dismiss();
        reciep.setText("");
        msg.setText("");
        sub.setText("");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
}
```

В этой строке :

```
Transport.send(message);
```

Возникает ошибка:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP
>   host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465; W/System.err:   nested exception is:
>   W/System.err:     javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for
>   certification path not found.

Такая ошибка.Подскажете что делать?
P.S логин и пароль от аккаунта верные,в этом приере изменены

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17761173/4051947

Comment: вопрос все еще актуален,принимаю ответы